# SQL relationship with three table which has one intermediate table

Tags: sql, join

I have three table not able to write query to get mentioned output.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider:

```
select m.motorid, m.name, m.manufactureDate, p.price
from motor m
left join intermediate i on i.motorid = m.motorid
left join price p on p.refid = i.refid
```

Note that it is important to use `left join`s rather than regular `inner join`s, so motors that have no price are not evicted from the resultset.